# how to uniqify a list of dict in python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
d = [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':3, 'y':4}, {'x':1, 'y':2}]
```

`{'x':1, 'y':2}` comes more than once I want to remove it from the list.My result should be:

```
 d = [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':3, 'y':4} ]
```

**Note:**
 `list(set(d))` is not working here throwing an error.

Comment: `set()` will try to hash each element of the list you give it. A `dict` is not hashable in Python, which is why `set(d)` will throw a `TypeError`

Comment: is it always just two element dicts? Avoid this whole problem and use tuples instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - List of unique dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)

Comment: @tripleee this is not duplicate. the one you pointed is using a single attribute in the dictionary which is unique. in this case there is no unique attribute.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your value is hashable this will work:

```
>>> [dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in d)]
[{'y': 4, 'x': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1}]
```

EDIT:

I tried it with no duplicates and it seemed to work fine

```
>>> d = [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':3, 'y':4}]
>>> [dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in d)]
[{'y': 4, 'x': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1}]
```

and

```
>>> d = [{'x':1,'y':2}]
>>> [dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in d)]
[{'y': 2, 'x': 1}]
```

Comment: This works only if the order of the items is guaranteed to be consistent (ie x always before y) across all the dicts. I know consistent order is guaranteed for a single dicts, but i'm not so sure in this case.

Comment: `x.iteritems()` -> `tuple(x.iteritems())` or you're comparing generator objects.

Comment: but if there is no duplicate element then this is gives me the wrong result.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I changed that back that was some pre-mature optimization thanks

Comment: @ramesh.c: I tried it with no duplicates and it seemed to work okay

Comment: @GWW; what about if I only try to match 'x' key. If 'x' value matches it is a duplicate.

Comment: @ramesh That would need a different solution, and so you might get more focused answers if you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: this option will not work if the values of the dictionaries are mutable (e.g. another dict, list, set). in this case it works because the all the values are strings.

Answer (score 8):

Dicts aren't hashable, so you can't put them in a set. A *relatively* efficient approach would be turning the `(key, value)` pairs into a tuple and hashing those tuples (feel free to eliminate the intermediate variables):

```
tuples = tuple(set(d.iteritems()) for d in dicts)
unique = set(tuples)
return [dict(pairs) for pairs in unique]
```

If the values aren't always hashable, this is not possible at all using sets and you'll propably have to use the O(n^2) approach using an `in` check per element.

Comment: +1 for clarifying that dicts aren't hashable, hence the error with `set(d)`.

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Answer (score 7):

Avoid this whole problem and use namedtuples instead

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point','x y'.split())
better_d = [Point(1,2), Point(3,4), Point(1,2)]
print set(better_d)
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple loop:

```
tmp=[]

for i in d:
    if i not in tmp:
        tmp.append(i)        
tmp
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}]
```

Comment: 5 lines vs. 1 (in GWW's answer) and not even equally readable... this is why terseness isn't evil in right doses.

Comment: actually it's only 4 (don't count the print). :-) Regarding the readability, well simplicity is in the eye of the beholder :-)

Answer (score 4):

tuple the dict won't be okay, if the value of one dict item looks like a list.

e.g.,

```
data = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
]
```

using **[dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in data)]** will get the unique data.

However, same action on such data will be failed:

```
data = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1,2]},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1,2]},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': [3]}
]
```

ignore the performance, `json dumps/loads` could be a nice choice.

```
data = set([json.dumps(d) for d in data])
data = [json.loads(d) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dark magic(please don't beat me):

```
map(dict, set(map(lambda x: tuple(x.items()), d)))
```

Comment: `map` isn't dark magic, it's just an ugly way to write a list comprehension ;) But note that in Python 2, this is very ineficient as it creates several (three if I'm counting correctly) intermediate lists that totally aren't needed.

Comment: Ok, i agree that we have here several unneeded lists. However, as i can see all of the solutions published above are also using not a single list. But why map is an ugly way of list comprehension?

Comment: If by dark magic you mean obfuscated, then you could just as well have gone for `l=type;y,z,l,o=(map,l({}),set,l(()));y(z,l(o(x.items())for x in d))`. Nested map are generally not as intuitive to read compared to list comprehension.

Comment: @Artsimon: Mine for instance creates a tuple of `n` two-tuples from a generator, a set from an iterator and a single list containing `n` dictionaries. Yours is the same except that it doesn't use generators and iterators when it could.

Comment: @delnan: thank you for providing details. i am only starting my way in python(especially in understanding differences between iterators and generator), so any comments are very appreciated and always helpful.