# How do I remove dicts from a list with duplicate fields in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

Let's say I have a list of dicts. I define "duplicates" as any two dicts in the list that have the same value for the field "id" (even if the other fields are different). How do I remove these duplicates.

An example list would be something like:

```
[{'name': 'John' , 'id':1}, {'name': 'Mike' , 'id':5},{'name': 'Dan' , 'id':5}]
```

In this case, 'Mike' and 'Dan' would be duplicates, and one of them needs to be removed. It doesn't matter which one.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries

Comment: It's a little different, since that user wanted to remove dicts that were completely identical, whereas I wanted to remove dicts that were identical in a single field, even if all other fields were different.

Comment: No, the OP clarified in a comment that this is exactly what they wanted to do. The solution is identical. Even the field name is the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dump them into another dictionary, then pull them out after.

```
dict((x['id'], x) for x in L).values()
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function's list comprehension should solve your problem.

```
def f(seq):
    s = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x['id'] not in s and not s.add(x['id'])]
```