# How to make values in list of dictionary unique?

Tags: python, unique

I have a list of dictionaries in Python, which looks like following:

```
d = [{feature_a:1, feature_b:'Jul', feature_c:100}, {feature_a:2, feature_b:'Jul', feature_c:150}, {feature_a:1, feature_b:'Mar', feature_c:110}, ...]
```

What I want to achieve is that to keep the `feature_a`, `_b` and `_c` unique.

For example, if we have 3 entries which have the same `feature_a` and `_b`, but have 3 different values of `feature_c` `100`, `100`, `150`, then after the operation, it should be `100` and `150`.

How can I achieve this?

================================================================
UPDATE：

OK, Thanks for Anand's excellent answer, it works perfectly. However, I have a further question.

Suppose we have a new `feature_d` and the dictionary looks like:

```
d = [{feature_a:1, feature_b:'Jul', feature_c:100, feature_d:'A'}, {feature_a:2, feature_b:'Jul', feature_c:150, feature_d: 'B'}, {feature_a:1, feature_b:'Mar', feature_c:110, feature_d:'F'}, ...]
```

and I only want to deduplicate `feature_a`, `_b` and `_c`, but leave `feature_d` out. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong layout. Why not have a dictionary where the keys are the features and the values are `set`s?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the order of the initial `d` list is not important , you can take the `.items()` of each dictionary and convert it into a [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) , which is hashable, and then you can convert the whole thing to a `set()` or `frozenset()` , and then convert each `frozenset()` back to dictionary. Example -

```
uniq_d = list(map(dict, frozenset(frozenset(i.items()) for i in d)))
```

`sets()` do not allow duplicate elements. Though you would end up losing the order of the list. For Python 2.x , the `list(...)` is not needed, as `map()` returns a list.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
[{'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 100},
 {'feature_a': 2, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 150},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Mar', 'feature_c': 110},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 100},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 150}]
>>> uniq_d = list(map(dict, frozenset(frozenset(i.items()) for i in d)))
>>> pprint.pprint(uniq_d)
[{'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 100},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 150},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Mar', 'feature_c': 110},
 {'feature_a': 2, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 150}]
```

---

For the new requirement -

> However, what if that I have another feature_d but I only want to dedup feature_a, _b and _c
>
> If two entries which have same feature_a, _b and _c, they are considered the same and duplicated, no matter what is in feature_d

A simple way to do this is to use a set and a new list, add only the features you need to the set, and check using only the features you need. Example -

```
seen_set = set()
new_d = []
for i in d:
    if tuple([i['feature_a'],i['feature_b'],i['feature_c']]) not in seen_set:
        new_d.append(i)
        seen_set.add(tuple([i['feature_a'],i['feature_b'],i['feature_c']]))
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> d = [{'feature_a':1, 'feature_b':'Jul', 'feature_c':100, 'feature_d':'A'},
...  {'feature_a':2, 'feature_b':'Jul', 'feature_c':150, 'feature_d': 'B'},
...  {'feature_a':1, 'feature_b':'Mar', 'feature_c':110, 'feature_d':'F'},
...  {'feature_a':1, 'feature_b':'Mar', 'feature_c':110, 'feature_d':'G'}]
>>> seen_set = set()
>>> new_d = []
>>> for i in d:
...     if tuple([i['feature_a'],i['feature_b'],i['feature_c']]) not in seen_set:
...         new_d.append(i)
...         seen_set.add(tuple([i['feature_a'],i['feature_b'],i['feature_c']]))
...
>>> pprint.pprint(new_d)
[{'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 100, 'feature_d': 'A'},
 {'feature_a': 2, 'feature_b': 'Jul', 'feature_c': 150, 'feature_d': 'B'},
 {'feature_a': 1, 'feature_b': 'Mar', 'feature_c': 110, 'feature_d': 'F'}]
```

Comment: Hi, Anand, Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. However, what if that I have another `feature_d` but I only want to dedup `feature_a`, `_b` and `_c`? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question with a sample dictionary for that?

Comment: Asssume two elements which have `feature_a` and `_b` and `_c` same but different `_d` what happens then? Are they considered duplcate of each other?

Comment: Yes, if two entries which have same `feature_a`, `_b` and `_c`, they are considered the same and duplicated, no matter what is in `feature_d`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anand. Excellent answer!

Comment: @AnandSKumar wouldn't a `not in` statement turn a list basically into a set? so wouldn't saying `not in seen_set` be a bit kinda redundant? because `seen_set` is already a `set` and can't have duplicates? why not use a `list` instead of a `set`?

Comment: `not in` will not do any kind of conversion , where did you read that? Also, containment check in `set` is O(1) (Constant time) , whereas containtment check in `list` is O(n) , so using set would be faster. And sets cannot hold duplicates , though that property is not exactly used in this context.

Comment: what I meant by `turn a list basically into a set` is if you use a `not in` on a list then the list can't contain duplicates and is basically like a `set` not actually convert into one. so sets are faster than lists?

Comment: Yes , sets are very much faster than list , try it out yourself . you will see. Create a list of 100000 items and create a set of 100000 items and try to do `elem in list` and `elem in set` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar well ok that would make using sets better then. thanks Anand :D