# Get a unique set of dicts

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
l = [
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-04', 'Code': u'SDRENT'},
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-05', 'Code': u'SDRENT'},
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-05', 'Code': u'HDRENT'},
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-05', 'Code': u'HDRENT'}
]
```

Doing a unique set of the above would get me:

```
l = [
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-04', 'Code': u'SDRENT'},
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-05', 'Code': u'SDRENT'},
      {'FutureReleaseStartDate': u'2016-10-05', 'Code': u'HDRENT'}
]
```

How would I do the above? Note that I am not looking to get unique objects based on a key, such as [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries), but on the entire object in the array.

Comment: Please read the whole page before complaining. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38521207/2301450

Comment: @vaultah yes that answer is helpful, thank you for linking to it.