# How to keep a unique bag of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I use a `set` when I need to keep a reference list of values which I want to keep unique (and later on, check if something is `in` that `set`). This does not work with `dict` because it is not hashable.

There are [quite a few techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries) to "uniquify" a `list` of `dict` but all of them assume that I have a final `list`, which I want to reduce to unique elements.

How to do that in a dynamic way? For a `set` I would just `.add()` and element and would know that it will be added only if it is unique. Is such a (EDIT: ideally, but not necessarily) built-in mechanism available for a bag of `dict` (I use the word "bag" because I do not want to limit possible answers to any data container)

Comment: You can implement a custom set-like object using a custom hash function based on dictionaries ?

Comment: ["Bag" means "multiset"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset); maybe you should just ask about hashable/immutable `dict`s and ignore the container's type.

Comment: So every time a key or value changes in any `dict` your set-like structure will be re-tested?

Comment: What about using an immutable [frozen dict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict/)?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I am not sure what you mean? I would like to add dicts to that container and just ensure that there are no duplicates (and later check against that container). Once they are in, they will not change.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: it looks like this is exactly what I am looking for (from first tests). Would you mind turning this into an answer? I will test more in depth and be back. Thanks.

Comment: @WoJ Ah I see, it was not clear to me that the dictionaries would be fixed, in that case clearly some kind of frozen-dict type construct is the way to go, relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be

Comment: The problem is easily solved by switching from ``someset.add(somedict)`` to ``someset.update(somedict.items())``.  See my answer below for an example.  It is pretty easy to do dynamic, incremental updates in this fashion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [frozen dict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict/) which is an immutable implementation of a regular dict.

This approach should allow you to use frozen dicts inside a set.

```
>>> from frozendict import frozendict
>>> x = [frozendict({'a':2, 'b':3}),frozendict({'b':3, 'a':2})]
>>> set(x)
{<frozendict {'b': 3, 'a': 2}>}
>>> frozendict({'b': 3, 'a': 2}) in set(x)
True
>>> frozendict({'b': 4, 'a': 2}) in set(x)
False
>>> frozendict({'a': 2, 'b': 3}) in set(x)
True
```

Comment: Thanks. I am adding some code (my first tests) to your answer to show the usage

Answer (score 1):

> The set classes are implemented using dictionaries. Accordingly, the
>   requirements for set elements are the same as those for dictionary
>   keys; namely, that the element defines both **eq**() and **hash**().
>   As a result, sets cannot contain mutable elements such as lists or
>   dictionaries. However, they can contain immutable collections such as
>   tuples or instances of ImmutableSet.

So if you only want to use built-ins, you could convert your dictionaries to a tuple of tuples upon entering them to a set, and converting them back to dictionaries when you want to use them.

```
dict_set = set()
dict_set.add(tuple(a_dict.items()))
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround. However, there is no guarantee on the sorting of items (I think) so you may end up with duplicated entries. That may be solved by adding a `sort` there. And this is assuming that both keys and values are hashable (which I think that it is a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Thank you - I edited my question to soften the "built-in" part, what I meant was "without completely rewriting a set-like container for dicts". Your solution is great, I have doubts about the order of the tuple elements (similar to @MariusSiuram)

Comment: @MariusSiuram Instead of a `sorted` `tuple`, you could also just use a `frozenset`.

Answer (score 0):

> For a set I would just .add() and element and would know that it will be added only if it is unique.

Instead of `add()`, use `update()` or `|=` with the dictionary's items.  That will meet your goal of adding dynamically and incrementally while "knowing that it will be added only if it is unique.":

```
>>> d = dict(raymond='red')
>>> e = dict(raymond='blue')
>>> f = dict(raymond='red')

>>> s = set()
>>> s |= d.items()
>>> s |= e.items()
>>> s |= f.items()
>>> s
```