# Python: Make list of dictionaries unique with respect to one key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries where one of the key values is NOT unique:

```
arr = [{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}, 
       {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080},
       {'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020},]
```

I want to make the given array unique in regards to the 'host' key so that the final output would be:

```
result = [{'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}, 
          {'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020},]
```

or it could be:

```
result = [{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}, 
          {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080},]
```

What is the Pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: Given there are clashes, should the first item be retained?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem great question! It can be either one I don't mind.

Comment: Convert it to a dict (or OrderedDict if the order is important) with `host`s as keys and `port`s as values.

Comment: @glibdud could you please provide your answer in code?

Comment: Do you care that if the host key is not unique you will lose the port value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - List of unique dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)

Comment: @zipa this is NOT a duplicate because it's regards to the uniqueness of only one of the key values and NOT all of them

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer thanks for the question. I don't care to lose them - no.

Answer (score 8):

You could just convert to a dict and extract the values:

```
>>> { d['host']: d for d in arr }.values()
[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020}, {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}]
```

For Python3, you could convert the `dict_values` to a `list`:

```
>>> list({d['host']: d for d in arr}.values())
[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020}, {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}]
```

If you want to keep the original order (minus the `host` duplicates), you could use an OrderedDict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict( (d['host'], d) for d in arr).values())
[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020}, {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}]
```

Finally, if you want a list of dictionary with unique `host` **and** `port`, you could use a tuple as key:

```
>>> list(OrderedDict(((d['host'], d['port']), d) for d in arr).values())
[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}, {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}, {'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric! Now what if I wanted to do this on arr in place, so that the output is back on arr?

Comment: @etayluz: It's not really in place because it creates a new list and assigns it back to `arr`, but you could just write `arr = list(OrderedDict( (d['host'], d) for d in arr).values())`.

Comment: what if i need to filter by max and min of port?

Comment: @SivaSankar: Something like `[d for d in arr if 2000 < d['port'] < 4000]` possibly? It outputs `[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}]`

Comment: Assume I dont know the port value, I just need to store according to max/min/orderby first

Comment: @SivaSankar: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. You could write an official question on StackOverflow. If you do, be sure to show what you already tried and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the first entry:

```
arr = [{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}, 
       {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080},
       {'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 1020},]
hosts = set()
out = []
for entry in arr:
    if not entry['host'] in hosts:
        out.append(entry)
        hosts.add(entry['host'])
print(out)

#[{'host': '144.217.103.15', 'port': 3000}, {'host': '158.69.115.201', 'port': 8080}]
```