# How to remove duplicate items in python list

Tags: python-2.7

How to remove duplicate items in a list. For example spider gives me below output:

```
[
 {"category": "Movies", "id": 4},
 {"category": "Movies", "id": 5} 
 {"category": "Movies", "id": 4}
]
```

I want to remove 1st and last item because they are same. please help.

Comment: What is so specific about scrapy in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x will be your list

```
uniquex = []
deleted = []


for i in x:
    if i in uniquex:
        uniquex.remove(i)
        deleted.append(i)

    elif i not in deleted:
        uniquex.append(i)
```