# Python3: Comparing multiple dictionaries in a list / Deleting repeated entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Looks like this:

```
[{'direction': 'PLACE_A', 
    'line': 'S2', 
    'delay': 0, 
    'when': '2017-11-29T17:48:00+01:00', 
    'trip': 33738
    }

{'direction': 'PLACE_A', 
    'line': 'S2', 
    'delay': 0, 
    'when': '2017-11-29T17:48:00+01:00', 
    'trip': 33738
}
{'direction': 'PLACE_B', 
    'line': 'S1', 
    'delay': 0, 
    'when': '2017-11-29T17:51:00+01:00', 
    'trip': 33739
}
{'direction': 'PLACE_B', 
    'line': 'S1', 
    'delay': 0, 
    'when': '2017-11-29T17:55:00+01:00', 
    'trip': 33740
}
{'direction': 'PLACE_A', 
    'line': 'S2', 
    'delay': 0, 
    'when': '2017-11-29T17:48:00+01:00', 
    'trip': 33738
}]
```

Some of the entries appear twice or more: The value for **trip** is identical.

How can I reduce the list in a way that recurrent entries in the list of dictionaries are deleted? I tried something with set, but that didn't work here.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this give you what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries

Comment: @alan i think the problem is different, there they are checking only an `id` value to be unique, here the op wants to check if two dictionaries are the same or not

Comment: @Moshen. Same here. The ID is `trip`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Comment: @Alan Thanks a lot. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new list:

```
newlist = []
for item in oldlist:
    if item not in newlist:
        newlist.append(item)
```