# searching for distinct dict in a list

Tags: python

With the following list of dict:

```
[ {'isn': '1', 'fid': '4', 'val': '1', 'ptm': '05/08/2019 14:22:39', 'sn': '111111'  'procesado': '0'}, 
 {'isn': '1', 'fid': '4', 'val': '0', 'ptm': '05/08/2019 13:22:39', 'sn': '111111', 'procesado': '0'},
<...> ]
```

I would need to compare for each dict of the list if there are other element with:

- equal fid
- equal sn
- distinct val (if val(elemX)=0 then val(elemY)=1)
- distinct ptm (if val=0 of elemX then ptm of elemX < ptm of elemY)

This could be done in a traditional way using an external for loop an internal while, but this is not the optimal way to do it.

---

Trying to find a way to do that, I tried with something like this:

```
   for p in lista:
        print([item for item in lista if ((item["sn"] == p["sn"]) & (item["val"] == 0) & (p["val"] == 1) & (
               datetime.strptime(item["ptm"], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') < datetime.strptime(p["ptm"],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')))])
```

But this does not work (and also is not optimal)

Comment: This `&` is not `and` in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a mapping from `(fid,sn,val)` onto a list of candidates (the whole `dict`, its index, or just its `ptm` (shown below), depending on what output you need).  Also check whether any of its **opposite numbers** (under `(fid,sn,!val)`) are already present and do the `ptm` comparison if so:

```
seen={}
for d in dd:
  f=d['fid']; s=d['sn']; v=int(d['val'])
  p=datetime.strptime(d['ptm'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
  for p0 in seen.get((f,s,not v),()):
    if p0!=p and (p0<p)==v: …
  seen.setdefault((f,s,v),[]).append(p)
```

If you have a large number of values with the same key, you could use a **tree** to hasten the `ptm` comparisons, but that seems unlikely here.  Using **real data types** for the individual values, and perhaps a `namedtuple` to contain them, would of course make this a lot nicer.