# append all values in a dict if all elements exists and remove duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a scenario where I have three dictionaries which I want merge into one but the condition is while I compare the three dictionaries with key `name` if there are duplicates need to remove them.

Here is what I have tried :

```
dict1= {'d1': [{'name': 'app1', 'id': 7134}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 242}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 67},{'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098}]}

dict2= {'d2': [{'name': 'app1 ', 'id': 30}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 82}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17}]}

dict3= {'d3': [{'name': 'app1', 'id': 70}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 2582},{'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]}

dict2 = {i:j for i,j in dict2.items() if i not in dict1}
dict3 = {i:j for i,j in dict3.items() if i not in dict2}
```

But the same do not give results also I am not sure how to compare three dicts for that matter.
and since if you look at the data `dict1` is having an element `'name': 'app1'` where as the same element is there in `dict2` like this `'name': 'app1 '` (with a space) not sure how to format this as well and get a final dict like below as result.

```
{'final': [{'name': 'app1 ', 'id': 30}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 82}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17},{'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098},{'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]}
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb Python 3 would be fine, is there any major difference in use od modules in them if yes, then I would like to know both.

Comment: How do you select which dict to keep. Ex `{'name': 'app1 ', 'id': 30}` and not `{'name': 'app1', 'id': 7134}` or `{'name': 'app1', 'id': 70}`?

Comment: @Rakesh I would keep any one of them but not with the space one so can `strip()` be used later if there are trailing whitespaces in the final dict name ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, taking advantage of this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092590/6159698) (useful for python-2.x alternatives) that will remove duplicates without any particular rule:

```
final_dict = dict()
final_dict["final"] = dict1["d1"] + dict2["d2"] + dict3["d3"]
final_dict["final"] = list(
    {v['name'].strip():v for v in final_dict["final"]}.values()
)  # see usage of .strip() to handle space problems you mention

print(final_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'final': [
  {'name': 'app1', 'id': 70},
  {'name': 'app2', 'id': 2582},
  {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17},
  {'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098},
  {'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]
}
```

Comment: there is no such restriction in that like which name to keep from which dict if it matches in all 3 dicts then keep any one of them in the final dict

Comment: Then the answer I suggested works: you'd keep any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Updater code:

```
dict1= {'d1': [{'name': 'app1', 'id': 7134}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 242}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 67},{'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098}]}
dict2= {'d2': [{'name': 'app1 ', 'id': 30}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 82}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17}]}
dict3= {'d3': [{'name': 'app1', 'id': 70}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 2582},{'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]}
final = {'final':[]}
for i in dict1['d1']:
    final['final'].append(i)

for k,l in zip(dict3['d3'],range(len(dict1['d1']))):
    if k['name'] == final['final'][l]['name']:
        final['final'][l].update(k)
    else:
        final['final'].append(k)
for j,l in zip(dict2['d2'],range(len(dict1['d1']))):
    if j['name'].strip() == final['final'][l]['name'].strip():
        final['final'][l].update(j)
    else:
        final['final'].append(j)
```

This gives:

```
{'final': [{'name': 'app1 ', 'id': 30}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 82}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17}, {'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098}, {'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group all dictionaries together by `name` using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for lst in (dict1.values(), dict2.values(), dict3.values()):
    for sublst in lst:
        for dic in sublst:
            d[dic["name"].strip()].append(dic)
```

Then choose the dictionaries with the smallest `id` value using `min()`. This still works for the requirements since it still chooses one dictionary and matches the output requested.

```
from operator import itemgetter

result = {'field': [min(x, key=itemgetter('id')) for x in d.values()]}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'field': [{'name': 'app1', 'id': 30}, {'name': 'app2', 'id': 82}, {'name': 'yest app', 'id': 17}, {'name': 'abc jam app', 'id': 6098}, {'name': 'availabla2z', 'id': 6667}]}
```