# Find last index from list of dict with same values of key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dict in python like this

```
list_qty = [{'id':1,'qty': '10'},{'id':1,'qty': '15'},{'id':2,'qty': '7'},{'id':2,'qty': '20'},{'id':2,'qty': '30'}]
```

i want to get `last index` of dict from `list_qty` that have same id

output that i want is:

```
list_qty2 = [{'id':1,'qty': '15'},{'id':2,'qty': '30'}]
```

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Like, iterate over the list backwards, keeping track of the IDs you've already seen (in a set for time efficiency) then add dicts with ID's you haven't seen to a resulting list?

Answer (score 1):

Dict in Python updates the value of the same key. So you can try something like this:

Python 3.x

```
list_qty = [{'id':1,'qty': '10'},{'id':1,'qty': '15'}, {'id':2,'qty': '7'},{'id':2,'qty': '20'},{'id':2,'qty': '30'}]
list_qty2=list({v['id']:v for v in list_qty}.values())
print(list_qty2)

[{'id': 1, 'qty': '15'}, {'id': 2, 'qty': '30'}]
```

Python 2.7

```
list_qty = [{'id':1,'qty': '10'},{'id':1,'qty': '15'}, {'id':2,'qty': '7'},{'id':2,'qty': '20'},{'id':2,'qty': '30'}]
list_qty2={v['id']:v for v in list_qty}.values()
print list_qty2

[{'id': 1, 'qty': '15'}, {'id': 2, 'qty': '30'}]
```