# Explanation for List of unique dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

The approved solution for this question [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries) worked successfully for me too but I didn't understand what is actually going on.

Can someone explain this, please?

Comment: The answer created a new dict with the key as `id` Hence removing the duplicate values from the previous dict.

Comment: This is not an on-topic question. It will be more suitable to comment on the answer itself asking for clarifications. I see that you can't do that but that is still not enough for an answer. There is an explanation in the answer itself, what did you not understand? Did you try working with a visualizer to see what happens? This will help you far more than anyone can explain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries)