# Builtin exclusive() for iterables?

Tags: python, list

set() is not an option, it only works with iterables, that contain hashable items.
Currently I'm using this function:

```
def exclusive(arr):
        return arr.__class__({str(i):i for i in arr}.values())
```

Is there a builtin one?
P.S. Don't suggest your functions. I only ask for a builtin one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38521207/9835872 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your question title specifies lists only and lists are iterables, so what's wrong with using a `set`? Also sets are not limited to immutable items. Did you mean hashable?

Comment: And have you considered `frozenset`?