# Remove duplicate 2D dict values

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have the following list of dicts:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'192.168.20.10/32': [{1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}],
             '192.168.20.20/32': [{1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
                                  {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}]})
```

I would like to **iterate over this list object and remove the duplicate list items**.

The end result would look something like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                {'192.168.20.10/32': [{1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
                                      {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}],
                 '192.168.20.20/32': [{1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
                                      {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}]})
```

Please note that I am using defaultdict from collections above:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Comment: It might be more worthwhile to correct it at the source, i.e don't create this pointless list of 1-element dictionaries in the first place, and contain a dictionary directly.

Comment: Shouldn't be '192.168.20.20/32': [{1: 'aaaaa11111\n'}, {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}, {2: 'aaaaa11111\n'}]}?

Comment: Can you add code that can be run directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (if resulting order does not matter):

```
adict = {
    '192.168.20.10/32': [
        {1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}
    ],
    '192.168.20.20/32': [
        {1: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
        {2: 'aaaaa11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'},
        {2: 'bbbbb11111\n'}
    ]
}

for k, v in adict.items():
    adict[k] = list(map(dict, (set([tuple(obj.items()) for obj in v]))))
print(adict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092607/11574713.

Calling your dictionary `first_dict`, run the dicts through a set by converting them into a string (JSON), and then bring them back to dicts.

```
import json

for k in first_dict:
    first_dict[k] = [json.loads(j) for j in set([json.dumps(i) for i in first_dict[k]])]
```

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'192.168.20.10/32': [{'2': 'bbbbb11111\n'},
              {'1': 'aaaaa11111\n'}],
             '192.168.20.20/32': [{'2': 'aaaaa11111\n'},
              {'2': 'bbbbb11111\n'},
              {'1': 'aaaaa11111\n'}]})
```