# getting unique values from a list of dict

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to uniqify a list of dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280978/how-to-uniqify-a-list-of-dict-in-python)

I have a list as follows

```
[
{'x':'1','y':'1'},{'x':'2','y':'2'},{'x':'1','y':'1'}
]
```

I want to get a new list as follows (unique elements)

```
[
{'x':'1','y':'1'},{'x':'2','y':'2'}
]
```

What's the best way?

Comment: Are the two identical dicts in the example different objects (i.e., two objects with distinct ids)?  If so, the problem is more complex, since methods of making a unique list such as casting to a set, etc. will not work.

Comment: Thanks  @DSM , your suggesion works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import ast

l = [
{'x':'1','y':'1'},{'x':'2','y':'2'},{'x':'1','y':'1'}
]

[ast.literal_eval(el1) for el1 in set([str(el2) for el2 in l])]
```

Usually an easy solution for keeping unique elements is to add them to a set. However, since a dict is unhashable (can't be put in a set), I provided a workaround. First, the dicts are converted to strings, placed in a set (to keep the unique ones), and then converted back to dicts using ast.literal_eval.

Comment: Why not use a dict of repr(dict) -> dict?

Comment: Or, do what black_dragon did, cast to tuples then back..

Comment: Does `str(d)` always iterate over the key, value pairs in the same order?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> lst = [{'x':'1','y':'1'},{'x':'2','y':'2'},{'x':'1','y':'1'}]
>>> map(dict, set(tuple(x.items()) for x in lst))
[{'y': '1', 'x': '1'}, {'y': '2', 'x': '2'}]
>>>
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure this works.  I don't know if it's guaranteed that two equal dicts have their `.items()` return in the same order.

Comment: This will not work in Python3.