# How to remove duplicates from Python list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries and I would like to remove all dicts that are duplicates in `number`. Keep only the last!

Example:

List of dicts:

```
student_data = [{'number':'1234', 'url':'www.abc.com'}, {'number':'9999', 'url':'www.abc.com'}, {'number':'1234', 'url':'www.xyz.com'}]
```

As you can see in we have 2 dicts where `number` is 1234. Therefore I remove the first dict and keep the last:

List of dicts:

```
student_data = [{'number':'9999', 'url':'www.abc.com'}, {'number':'1234', 'url':'www.xyz.com'}]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511/python-list-of-unique-dictionaries

Comment: The duplicate assumes that a dictionary is repeated if it has the same `id`. It does not check the other fields. Wrong dupe

Comment: This one is more like it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280978/how-to-uniqify-a-list-of-dict-in-python/6281063 . This should do `[dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in L)]`